# Is it possible to change the statusline color in Vim 8 terminal windows?

Tags: terminal, terminal-buffer

I would like to change the default green terminal statusline below to my usual colorscheme statusline color:

[image: terminal_green_bar]

Is this possible? There is no mention of it in `:h terminal`.

Comment: The Statusline for the terminal uses the `StatusLineTerm` and `StatusLineTermNC` highlighting group.

Comment: Thanks @christian, if you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The still somewhat new internal terminal implementation of Vim 8 uses the `StatusLineTerm` highlighting group for the active window and the `StatusLineTermNC` highlighting group for the statusline of an inactive window.

So you might want to tweak the corresponding highlighting groups like this:

```
:hi StatusLineTerm ctermbg=red ctermfg=black guibg=#ff0000 guifg=black
:hi StatusLineTermNC ctermbg=red ctermfg=darkblack guibg=darkred guifg=black
```

Of course use whatever looks good to your style :)